# what is instagram API to return users Data

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to display posts in my site from Instagram account but I don't know perfect API to use  I have used difference alternatives but they didn't meet my expectation may any one one may know more than I do

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: does https://developers.facebook.com/docs/features-reference/oembed_read this help?

Comment: Note: using the graph API requires an [App Review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-review)